# In which case "Left OUTER JOIN" is better over "NOT IN" query and In which case "NOT IN" or "NOT EXIST" or "IN"?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi can anyone explain me where I should use Outer Join and where I should use NOT IN or NOT EXIST query.

Which one is better in which case ?

Comment: First of all If you tried something, post it here. Then you can get good attention for your problem rather than asking what is best or not.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if EXISTS or NOT EXISTS is applicable, use it. They are semi-join. It returns result immediately when the first match or not match row is found, and it throw away what just found.

It makes no sense to say which is better just by syntax. SQL Server data engine optimizer will decide the actual execution plan. Quite different query might generate the exact same execution plan. If you're not sure which is better, check you actual execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

We can use joins when we need to get data from different tables by connecting them.

And We can use **IN, NOT IN or NOT exists** in our where clause to filter our data according to our requirement.

Refer these links for more info..

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

[NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173041/3156647)

Answer (score 0):

Generally not exists is faster in SQL server than the others for the equivalent query. However, with a left join you may not be doing an equivalent query. Left joins are also used when you want some of the data from both tables. For instance you have a User table and an Address table, but not all users have addresses. So you use a left join to get the addresses that you do have and a null value for those you do not. You can't do this with not exists or not in so left join is your only choice.